# can I solve a captcha (function that getting image and returning string) by code

Tags: c#, image, captcha

I'm sending many messages to my gmail account by my code, sometimes I get an exception indicating that I sent many messages and reached the limit, then I can't send.

When i enter to my gmail in the website , I get a captcha that I need to solve it, and after solving it I can send my message successfully.

My idea is to navigate to `gmail.com` when I get that exception and to fill my gmail and password (programatically), and to get the captcha as an image and to solve it by code .

Can I achieve my idea ??

Comment: Captchas are specifically designed to be difficult to process using automated processes.

Comment: Possibly.  But it's going to be an uphill battle.  Start by doing at least *some* research into existing captcha solving projects, there are lots of them out there.  But also realize that you're trying to beat *Google* at this game.  They have a non-insignificant budget devoted specifically to *preventing* what you're doing.

Comment: yes I know, I understand that there is no way for that purpose ??

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: This is [the XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) - if you need to send lots of mail, work on running your own mail server.

Comment: Why don't you just throttle your email sending, which should be fairly simple vs. circumventing a thing made to avoid computer deciphering?

Comment: @48klocs what do you mean by work on running your own mail server ??

Answer (score 13, accepted):

CAPTCHA stands for `Completely Automated Public Turing test to tell Computers and Humans Apart`.

The whole point of `captcha` is that they cannot be solved by a computer.

Have people broken `captchas`? **Yes**

Do websites update their `captcha` systems when they are broken? **As soon as possible.**

The people who are trying to break `captcha` are usually spammers who want to circumvent the `captcha` which is designed to limit their spam.

If you have a legitimate reason for having a higher rate, I would recommend contacting the company in question, in this case Google.

Comment: I know , but I ask if there is anyway of solving it ??

Comment: @KaramNajjar yes, by looking at it and typing it in

Comment: AMR , should I laugh ?

Comment: @KaramNajjar: No, you should accept the reality of the situation.  The captcha is Google's way of telling you that you're misusing the service they provide.  Use another service, or in some way change your account to accommodate the service you require.  (A Google apps business account, maybe?)

Comment: @David thank you , but how to achieve this , how to get permission for sending many messages ?

Comment: @KaramNajjar We aren't google support, you should go ask them.

Comment: @KaramNajjar: By checking Google's terms of service, and contacting them to see if they offer the services you need.  It's entirely possible that they don't.